# How can I convert a list of data frames into a data frame of lists using purrr or tidyr?

Tags: r, purrr

This question seems like it has probably been answered before, but I have not found anything exactly on point. I have a list of data frames, which I would like to convert to a data frame with two columns -- **ID** and **data**. **ID** should be a column of integers, and **data** should be a column of data frames. Here's a toy example of the list of data frames that I would like to convert to a single data frame with two rows (one for each unique ID) and two columns (**ID** and **data**):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)

list <- list(tibble(ID = rep(1, 4),
                    a = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                    b = c(4, 3, 2, 1)),
             tibble(ID = rep(2, 3),
                    c = c(4, 5, 6),
                    d = c(6, 5, 4))
           )
```

This seems like a job for `tidyr::unnest`, but my effort to use that function was unsuccessful:

```
df <- unnest(list, cols = ID)
#> Error in UseMethod("unnest") : 
#>  no applicable method for 'unnest' applied to an object of class "list"
```

I was also unable to accomplish my goal using `tibble`:

```
df <- tibble(list, .rows = ID)
#> Error in tibble_quos(xs[!is.null], .rows, .name_repair) : 
#>  object 'ID' not found
```

How can I convert my list of data frames into a data frame of lists, ideally using `purrr` or `tidyr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the output you want correctly, you can do

```
list %>% map_df(~.x %>% nest(cols=-ID))
```

Since `nest` requires a data.frame, you need to map over the data frames in the list to do the mapping. Then `map_df` will combine everything into one data.frame in the end.

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. Could you explain why -- within the anonymous function in map_df --  I need to pipe .x to nest? In other words, since I'm already piping list to map_df, why doesn't nest recognize that .x is the same as list?

Comment: `.x` isn't the same as list; `.x` is the place holder for each tibble that you have stored in the list.  Maybe it's more clear if I write it like this: `list %>% map_df(~nest(.x, cols=-ID))`

Comment: Ah, I see -- thank you. This does make it clearer to me. I recognize the syntax in the example from other purrr-related code, and your comment (in conjunction with the answer) also helps me to understand that other code.

Comment: Dear @MrFlick is it possible to use `unsplit` function for this case? If that's the case I would be grateful to know how.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I can't see anyway you could use `unsplit` to get nested data frames from this input. Unsplit might work in the case where the same columns are present in each item in the list, but not different columns. At least I can't see anyway to do it because the data was clearly not created from a "normal" split.

Comment: @MrFlick, could `.x` be replaced by `.` in your example?

Comment: @GuedesBF. Yes. the `?rlang::as_function` helper allows you to use `.` or `.x`

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you very much for your answer. I guess you are right, in this case it may not be quite useful.